# when to use Serializable backing bean in JSF?

Tags: jsf

when to use Serializable backing bean in JSF?
is there any factors to go for serialization like View Scope, Session Scope, Application Scope or is anything else which requires bean to be serialized.

Comment: what jsf impl do you use and what is the state saving method?
are you seeing errors incase bean is not serializable?

Comment: i am using JSF 2 with state saving to SERVER and also getting :
WARNING: Setting non-serializable attribute value into ViewMap: (key: Test1Bean, value class: com.backingbeans.Test1Bean)

Comment: Hi, did you get any more insight on this? Is it really ok *not* to enable serialization on all backing beans?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd say that session-scoped beans are eligible for serialization, because the the servlet container tries to serialize everything in the session in case it (the container) is restarted.

Comment: and what about ApplicationScoped beans, are they created new ?